# python pptx add image without image file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pptx

I create a pptx file using python pptx package (python 2.7)

I have a image in memory that i create using matplotlib with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()

plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.xlabel(x_l)
plt.ylabel(y_l)
plt.title(title)

x_values = range(len(times))

plt.xticks(x_values[::len(x_values)/24], range(24))

plt.yticks(range(len(dates)),dates)
plt.axes().set_aspect('auto')

return plt.gcf()
```

Later i try to add this image to the pptx file using

```
pic = shapes.add_picture(image, left,top = top, width= width, height = height )
```

and get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'read'

The code works if i save the image to a file and then read it to the pptx file with the path, with exactly the same code.
[adding image file to pptx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742178/python-pptx-slide-shapes-add-picture-not-recognizing-image-files)

I found only how to add an image file to the pptx, and nothing about adding image from memory.

I need to add it without saving any file to disk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save it to an in-memory StringIO stream (a "file-like object") and feed the StringIO object to python-pptx.

```
import StringIO

image_stream = StringIO.StringIO()
image.save(image_stream)
pic = shapes.add_picture(image_stream, left, top, width, height)
image_stream.close() # probably optional, but couldn't hurt
```

These other two questions have additional details.

- [How to pass PIL image to Add_Picture in python-pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450718/how-to-pass-pil-image-to-add-picture-in-python-pptx)
- [Python PIL: how to write PNG image to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string)

Comment: could you please detail the answer so i will be able to accept it?

Comment: @captainshai I've added a more explicit code snippet